# Can we not apply the Hensel Lifting Lemma in this case?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Check if the equation $x^2=-1 \text{ in } \mathbb{Z}_2$ has a solution, and if it has, calculate the three first positions of the solution.

So, we are looking for a solution $\pmod 2$, one solution $\pmod{2^2}$ and one $\pmod {2^3}$, right?

That's what I have tried:

$$\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$$

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \Rightarrow x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$

So, when $x \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, the equation $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod 2$ is not satisfied.

$$x \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \Rightarrow x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \equiv -1 \pmod 2$$

So, the equation $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod 2$ is satisfied, when $x \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.

Therefore, $1$ is the only solution of $x^2=-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

$$x_0=1$$

We are looking for a $x_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$x_1^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {2^2} \text{ such that } x_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$

$$x_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \Rightarrow 2 \mid x_1-1 \Rightarrow \exists a_1 \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } x_1=1+2a_1$$

$$x_1^2+1=(1+2a_1)^2+1 \equiv 2 \pmod {2^2}$$

So: $x_1^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{2^2} \Leftrightarrow 2 \equiv 0 \pmod {2^2}$, that is a contradiction.

Is it right ? If so, does this mean that we cannot apply the Hensel Lifting Lemma in this case? Why not?

**EDIT:** Is there only one position of the solution? If so, how can we justify it?

Comment: Hensel lemma requires $\;f'(r)\neq 0\;$, with $\;r\;$ the root of the polynomial $\;f(x)\;$ . In this case, $\;f(x)=x^2+1\;$ and $\;f'(x)=2x=0\;$ , so Hensel won't work here.

Comment: So, is there only a first position of the solution?

Comment: @Timbuc Is there only one position of the solution? If so, how can we justify it?

Comment: I really don't know. I suspect there's only one solution (as Hensel' Lemma doesn't apply here), yet I can't prove it.

Comment: @Timbuc Could I also justify it, as I did at my initial post, where I found a contradiction?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation modulo $4$.

Comment: $$x_1=2k \Rightarrow x_1^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \not\equiv -1 \pmod 4 $$

$$x_1=2k+1 \Rightarrow x_1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \not\equiv -1 \pmod 4$$

But, how can I justify that we cannot apply the method, I applied at my original post?

Comment: @evinda Why do you want to justify being unable to apply a method, when you know that no method in existence can construct something that doesn't exist?  In any case, Timbuc answered this question quite clearly in the comments.

Comment: A ok.. Could I also justify it, as I did at my initial post, where I found a contradiction?

Comment: Yes, that part of the argument looks correct.  Be careful how it's worded—there are lots of wrong points in your post, like your claim that $1$ is a solution to $x^2=-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Isn't $1$ a solution of the equation $x^2=-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ?

Comment: No.  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has characteristic zero, so $1\neq -1$.  $1$ is a solution of that equation in $\mathbb{Z}_2/2\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, however.